# Extract Substring using Regular expression aka Regex

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, posix-ere

I have Snowflake POSIX BRE engine and wants to extract below substring from given text. POSIX doesn't support lookbehind and lookahead. Please help with regex expression.

Ex 1: 2022 CKL04 TER-PRO:CPT-REFRESH PRD|NPR
Substring Needed: CPT-REFRESH PRD

Ex 2 : 2022 CA4A TER-PRO:CPT-REFRESH PRD
Substring Needed: CPT-REFRESH PRD

Ex 3 : 2022 CDDR4A TER-PRO:CPT-LEASING PRD|MC|LQPRI13
Substring Needed: CPT-LEASING PRD

Ex 4 : 2022 CAP04A TER-PRO:PRODUCT|NPR
Substring Needed: PRODUCT

Ex 5 : 2022 CS040 TER-PRO:MS-PRD & SVC ANNUAL|NPR
Substring Needed: MS-PRD & SVC ANNUAL

I need all of the characters after : and before first | or end of the string if no | is available.

I am able to extract with lookahead and lookbehind using this regex (?<=:).+?(?=||$)  but I need solution for POSIX BRE without lookahead and lookbehind

Comment: would `[\w\-\s]+` work if then you just grab the second match?

Comment: Thanks. I added few more examples where it isn't working and match number also varies for different examples. Its showing also this error in Snowflake "Invalid regular expression: '[w-s]+', invalid character class range: w-s".

Comment: You can use lookahead and lookbehind regex in Snowflake using a JavaScript UDF. https://github.com/GregPavlik/SnowflakeUDFs/tree/main/RegularExpressions. You could also use instr and substr to extract the text without using regular expressions.

Comment: the regex I provided was not a range `w-s` it was `\w`, `\-`, and `\s`, for example 5 you'd need to add `&`, and only works if you can choose the second match

Comment: @depperm yeah it was not a range but character class but weird snowflake throwing this error

Comment: @GregPavlik let me try the Javascript UDF. I know it can be done via string functions but was looking to handle via regex.

Comment: @GregPavlik I tried first javascript function and it returns NULL with this query -- Select REGEXP_SUBSTR2('2022 CS268 TEAM-PRO:PRD&CX-NON REC SVC|AG|PRI','(?<=:).+?(?=\||$)',1,1,'',0)

Comment: POSIX BRE expression will be `:\([^|]*\)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It works exactly I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Logic is to start at `:` then keep capturing everything after that unless we encounter a `|`, at which point we just stop there. I am using a capture group so we don't include the preceding `:`

```
select regexp_substr(col,':([^|]+)',1,1,'e');
```

Comment: Thank you. Its works as I expected.